# Include parent and child items of GtkTreeStore in GtkEntryCompletion

Tags: gtk3, pygtk, glade

I have a `GtkEntryCompletion` declared as follows:

```
<object class="GtkEntryCompletion" id="search_entry_completion">
    <property name="model">menu_treestore</property>
    <property name="text_column">0</property>
</object>
```

The model is a `GtkTreeStore` with two columns, and column 0 is rendered as the text that should appear in the entry completion.
The problem is that as it is a `GtkTreeStore`, only the parent items are used in the completion.

So, for example, if I have:

```
test0
    test00
    test01
test1
```

Only `test0` and `test1` will be available for the entry completion. I can't change the model to a `GtkListStore`, so, is there a way to make all items of the `GtkTreeStore` available for the entry completion?
I'm using Python and Glade for the development of that task.

Comment: Don't know anything about this widget, but maybe check the documentation on [GtkEntryCompletion](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntryCompletion.html). I quote: "By default, the matching is done by comparing the entry text case-insensitively against **the text column of the model** (see gtk_entry_completion_set_text_column()), but **this can be overridden with a custom match function** (see gtk_entry_completion_set_match_func())."

Comment: @DanielF. and joaopaulo, I did some research on this and it seems the Treestore is searched for all entries, but the completion GUI is not setup to display the Tree hierarchy. I have an interest in this, if I find a solution, I will post here.

Comment: Ok, so a GtkEntryCompletion uses a GtkTreeModelFiltered internally, and any EntryCompletion or Combobox will not show child nodes of a filtered model. Off to Gtk master devs to see what can be done about it...

Comment: A hint... you can use a Treeview and a filtered store as a temporary workaround for now... that does work.

Comment: For reference, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1541